# re: What's the lightest Ubuntu desktop environment?

Tags: lubuntu, gui

I wanted to comment this post but I am new and my rep score isnt there.  My question is simple.  After installing a lighter weight GUI, is there really any advantage to uninstalling the original heavier one?

Comment: look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available

Comment: I have Lubuntu installed on some production servers. It's GUI enough to provide quick access to stuff with a mouse, but it's lightweight enough such that the GUI desktop manager uses <1% of the CPU most of the time. I have it installed on an SSD on one machine and it reboots back to the desktop in 13 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving on amount of used hard drive space for the unnecessary GUI?  Other than that, not really....if you aren't hurting for hard drive space, keep the second GUI in case you decide to go back to it later.

Comment: That was the answer I was expecting.  Just wanted to be sure they used no other resources than disk space when inactive.  Thanks!